# rich:select does not display selected value

Tags: select, jsf-2, richfaces

Following is my code

```
<rich:select id="cycle_group" value="#{menuCycleBean.menuCycleDetailTO.menuCycleGroupId}" defaultLabel="#{msg['gobal.select.default.label']}" 
                converter="javax.faces.Integer">
                <f:selectItems value="#{menuCycleBean.cycleGroupList}" var="n" itemLabel="#{n.label}" itemValue="#{n.id}" />
                </rich:select>
```

"menuCycleGroupId" is "Integer" Value and "n.id" is "String" using converter it is auto converter value from String to Int while submitting form but if i want to display selected option into rich:select then converter is not working ???
Converter only helps when submitting form what to do if i want to display selected record ?

Comment: If you were using `<h:selectOneMenu>` it should work just fine if you have indeed explicitly set the value of `#{menuCycleBean.menuCycleDetailTO.menuCycleGroupId}` to the desired integer value in bean's (post)constructor. Just for testing purposes, try replacing the `<rich:select>` by `<h:selectOneMenu>` to exclude if it's a bug in RichFaces or in your own code.

Comment: converter works fine for h:selectOneMenu but not with rich:select.

Comment: Then it's time to report it to the RichFaces guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rich:select having known issues with converter as well, i used h:selectOneMenu and it worked fine for me.